# Some first term of this sequence.

Tags: generating-functions

Let a generating function:
$$(x^n A(x))' $$
How to determine some first term of this sequence.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do the square brackets denote?

Comment: Is $A(x)$ some generating function, e.g. $A(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$? If so just use the product rule and differentiate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n n^n$ then

$$ (x^n A(x))' = nx^{n-1} x^n A(x) + x^n A'(x) = nx^{n-1} x^n A(x) + x^n \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nnx^{n-1}$$